# Angular Search and Add functionality

Tags: angular, primeng, azure-ad-msal

I have currently:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUsers();
  }

  getUsers() {
    this.http.get<User[]>("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users")
      .subscribe(users => {
        console.log(users);
        this.users = users;
    });
  }
```

and

```
<p-dropdown [options]="users" optionLabel="displayName" [showClear]="true" placeholder="Select a User"></p-dropdown>
```

I'm looking to do the following:

- Change to a Input and Search Button e.g. enters text and hits search button then it calls the API again with searching using startsWith query string

```
<input pInputText type="text" placeholder="Search User" class="w-full"/>

<p-button label="Search"></p-button>
```

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. This isn't a code writing service though so it's generally acceptable to try something first. Try it out and post your problems accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the getUsers method:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.getUsers();
}

getUsers(startsWith:string) {
  let url: string = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users";
  if (startWith)
    url += `?startsWith=${startsWith}`;
  this.http.get<User[]>(url)
    .subscribe(users => {
      console.log(users);
      this.users = users;
  });
}
```

and detect changes on your input

```
<input pInputText type="text" placeholder="Search User" (input)="getUsers($event)" class="w-full"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's go! Create a variable to store the search string and the function `getUsers()` should handle the string query, like this:

```
public searchQuery: string = '';

ngOnInit() {
  this.getUsers();
}

public getUsers(): void {
  if(this.searchQuery.trim() !== '') {
    this.http.get<User[]>(`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=startsWith(displayName,'${this.searchQuery}')`)
      .subscribe((users) => {
        this.users = users;
    });
  }
}
```

When clicking the button, the function `getUsers()` should be called. Use ngModel to synchronize the value with the input, like this:

```
<input pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchQuery" placeholder="Search User" class="w-full"/>

<p-button label="Search" (click)="getUsers()"></p-button>
```